# Update DotNetNuke user from another web application

Tags: web-services, dotnetnuke

DNN Ver 5.6.7
.NET 3.5

Anyone know of a way to access/update user accounts on a DNN site from another web application?

My goal is to allow customer service to update an employee's DNN password from an intranet app (that includes some other employee related, non-DNN data), but I'm not having any luck. I tried adding a simple web service to a virtual directory ([as described here](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Blogs/EntryId/1085/DotNetNuke-Tip-15-Running-a-webservice-inside-of-a-DNN-site.aspx)) to the DNN site, hoping the web service would then have access to all things DNN, but I'm not able to create instances of the UserInfoController - it's not instantiating the MemberProvider object.

```
UserController objUserController = new UserController();
UserInfo objUser = objUserController.GetUser(portalId, userId);
```

Each time, the objUserController object shows null for DotNetNuke.Security.Membership.MembershipProvider

Both the DNN site and our internal web app are hosted on the same server. Any suggestions are appreciated.

EDIT: In addition to all the DLLs in the DNN bin folder, I also copied everything from the DNN web.config into my web service web.config that looked DNN related

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if your WebService is inside DNN, this code must work:

```
UserInfo objUser = UserController.GetUserById(DotNetNuke.Entities.Portals.PortalSettings.Current.PortalId, userId);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intranet app is running on ActiveDirectory, I would look at some of the available ActiveDirectory integration modules.

If you can wait until DotNetNuke 6.2 comes out, it will include a built-in services layer which will allow you to authenticate and interact with DotNetNuke objects like users.

Comment: Thanks Bruce. Our intranet is running on AD. Can you recommend a specific AD integration module, or a good place to search for one?

Comment: Glanton solutions have a range of Active Directory modules that might be able to help.  All are available on the DNN store. http://store.dotnetnuke.com/vendor-profile/glanton-solutions

Answer (score 0):

I did this via http://iweb.adefwebserver.com/.

I added a web service method that took advantage of all the user related features in the DNN API (UserInfo, UserController, RoleController, etc.).